# Wordpress or front end Developer

Tags: wordpress, web-frontend

I started learning HTML,CSS,then when l came to Javascript, l discovered that 40% of the web are made by Wordpress, so here l stopped learning, and my question is why l should continue learning other technologies when l have something else that l can make same job through

Comment: WordPress is built using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. They’re worth learning still, because WordPress is just a tool, one of *many* you can use to build websites. WordPress excels at some things, and is terrible at other things. The more tools/skills you learn, the better chance you’ll have at being able to build the ideal site for your company/clients.

Comment: This is really an opinion-based question, and it's off-topic here. There's really no right answer to "what should I learn." Also, there is quite a bit of documentation and learning material you can read up on, regarding WordPress, and make your own decision based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress website are made with HTML, CSS, Javascript, PHP.

Yes, with Wordpress it is possible to create professional websites without coding. However, it is easy to be limited when you don't know how to code and you have very specific requirements.

I'm a web developper and many clients want to customize the functionality and appearance of their site. The needs are often so specific that no plugin is suitable and only a custom development can satisfy their request. This is where knowing how to code comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is a Content Management System which is built with `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript` and `PHP`. If you don't want to learn these languages and just want to go for drag and drop builders like `Elementor` and `WPBakery` etc. then you will be limited to build certain type of websites only and you will be limited on their functionality & customzation too.

On the other hand with learning these languages you will be able to create custom themes, plugins of almost any kind. You will be able to develop from small websites to e-commerce, point of sales, school or laboratory management systems and so on...

I agree with @Kirk Beard as he said in his comment they are totally worth learning and keep in mind that as WordPress excels at some things, it is terrible at other things.